# Insert Image from Symfony path with PHPExcel

Tags: symfony, phpexcel, vichuploaderbundle

I'm trying to insert images in my Excel using the `PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing` of PHPExcel (in this [Symfony Bundle](https://github.com/liuggio/ExcelBundle)) but I get this message all the time:

`File http://benefest.local/uploads/persons/image/58af244d3f58c_16143190_10210682923503464_8658615512523719175_n.jpg not found!`

Here is my code:

```
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
$objDrawing->setPath($path);
$objDrawing->setWidth(30);
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('A1');
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($phpExcelObject->getActiveSheet());
```

My images are uploaded by [VichUploaderBundle](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle), and I'm generating the absolute path through a function. which returns me `http://benefest.local/uploads/persons/image/58af244d3f58c_16143190_10210682923503464_8658615512523719175_n.jpg`

In a browser, this image is displayed!

Any clue?

Comment: Do you realize a difference between a URI and a file path? What function returns you is a URI which can be used to access the image via a web server. But you need a path to the file within your filesystem, so php can read it.

Comment: Thanks, I've also tried with the path only and I get the same error `File /uploads/persons/image/58af244d3f58c_16143190_10210682923503464_8658615512523719175_n.jpg not found!`

Comment: OK, I found the solution by setting the path to `./uploads/persons/image/58af244d3f58c_16143190_10210682923503464_8658615512523719175_n.jpg`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is based on my comments to this question.

There is a difference between URI and file path:

- **[URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier)** - used in browser, or being more general in HTTP protocol to get access to some resource via web-server
- **[File path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing))** - a link to some file within filesystem on your server/computer/etc.

Your function returns a URI string (`http://benefest.local/uploads/persons/image/58af244d3f58c_16143190_10210682923503464_8658615512523719175_n.jpg`), which can be used to access the image via a web server.

But `PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing` as well as other libraries use PHP's [filesystem functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php) to get access to some file locally. So you need to get a local file path, instead of URI (in you case it is `./uploads/persons/image/58af244d3f58c_16143190_10210682923503464_8658615512523719175_n.jpg`).